# UIButton label not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I have the following code

```
let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width    
let linkLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: contentHeight, width: 100, height: labelHeight))
    let linkButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 108, y: contentHeight, width: width - 108, height: labelHeight))
    mainScrollView.addSubview(linkLabel)
    mainScrollView.addSubview(linkButton)
    linkLabel.text = "Link:"
    linkButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(linkButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    linkButton.setTitle("http://example.com", forState: .Normal)
    linkButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: contentHeight)
```

And when view loads i see the following picture (Note that button is black rectangle):
[image]

So title is not visible but when i click on the button i can fetch its title property

```
func linkButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    print("button title = \(sender.titleLabel?.text)")
}
```

And i get the `button title = Optional("http://example.com")` but anyway button title is not visible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try making it bigger (taller) first - it might be too small to display the text.

Comment: How much is the "width" variable? Seems thats only a few pixels.

Comment: @sschale yes i've tried it but it doesn't helps

Comment: @derdida updated: width is equal to screen width

Comment: contentHeight = ? which value u take for that?

Comment: check your button width is perfectly fit with scrollview width

Comment: at the same time check mainScrollView width

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik mainScrollView width is equal to main view width

Comment: Have you tried `linkButton.setTitleColor(color: UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You skipped one step. You should add title color :-

```
linkButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 6):

Your button title is display but in white color.Give any color to button title it is there.There is no problem in your code.

```
linkButton.setTitle("http://example.com", forState: .Normal)
linkButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```